# Public Event Done(), RaiseEvent Done()

Tags: vb.net

What does Public Event Done(), RaiseEvent Done() do in this code? It is student form application teacher did this in class but he was so fast I couldn't catch all details.

```
Public Class Edit
    Public Event Done()

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
        If txtNumber.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please enter data to number")
            txtNumber.Focus()
            lblNumber.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Return
        Else
            lblNumber.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText
        End If

        Hide()
        RaiseEvent Done()
    End Sub
```

Comment: The first declares an event which that `Edit` class supports.  `RaiseEvent` fires the event for whatever might have subscribe to the event.,  Bad class name and a non standard event signature

Comment: It doesn't "do" anything.  It is just a notification, whatever *other* code that subscribes the event ought to do something useful.  Probably by using txtNumber, hard to guess.

Comment: You might like to [read this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html). It explains how to define and raise your own events just like those in the .NET Framework, e.g. the `Button.Click` event or the `TextBox.TextChanged` event.